# How to detect fake call log created by apps

Tags: android, calllog

Play store has numerous apps those creates fake call logs.But, sometimes it's important to detect **is that call log real or fake** to save yourself being a fool. Can anybody tell me how can we detect same?

Comment: To what apps are you reffering?

Answer (score 1):

If these apps are writing to the actual android call log, I don't think there is much you can do against that.

However, you might want to try the below solution, which can maintain your own call list based on the device behaviour.

In Android you can listen for incoming and outgoing calls, using a `BroadcastReceiver`. Here is a good tutorial for it:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/548416/Detecting-incoming-and-outgoing-phone-calls-on-And

If you implement it correctly, you will only receive events from calls being executed for real. So you can save them in your app's call log.

Comment: Sorry but this is not what I'm looking for.I want to detect fake call logs on others mobiles.